# switching from emacs to Preview of the compiled latex document, resets its display to page 1

Tags: mac, emacs, latex, osx-yosemite, preview

I just upgraded to Yosemite but had to reinstall various pieces and this is what happens. I edit my latex document using emacs, and preview its pdf using Preview (auctex is installed, and I compile latex directly in the emacs environment). After editing and recompiling, Preview used to show the same place of the document. Now, it switches always back to the first page, forcing me to return manually to the place which I was previewing. But, of course, I want to stay where I was in the Preview!

I suspect that this may not be a problem with Yosemite but that I must change something in auctex, emacs or Preview set up, but which parameter of which of these three, and how?

Thanks for any suggestions of how to fix this...

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm that Preview is setup properly. In the preferences for preview, you should have "start on the last viewed page" checked.

[image]

I'm guessing that you do, however. This is a bug with Preview.app in Yosemite. If the PDF is closed and you recompile, then reopen the pdf, it will be where you last left off. However, if the PDF is open and you recompile, it will jump to the top.

See also [a question on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153147/yosemites-preview-app-goes-to-top-of-document-when-pdf-changes)